# How to make OSX 10.7 app with AVFoundation code run on 10.6 without using AVFoundation code

Tags: macos

I have a Mac app I'm developing using XCode with the Base SDK set to 10.7 because I'm using code from the AVFoundation framework.  I'd like the app to run on 10.6, but since AVFoundation isn't available on 10.6, I want the app to just be able to run without any of the AVFoundation functionality (in other words, just have those features not be available).

When I run the app on 10.6, it immediately crashes because it can't find the dynamic library for AVFoundation.  I had thought that by setting the Deployment Target in my XCode project to 10.6 I would be able to get around this issue, but apparently it still tries to load the dynamic library.  Also, as pointed out on this page (http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/), I'm checking to make sure that the AVFoundation classes are available by doing this:

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"AmazingNewClass");
if(myClass) {
  //I can use “myClass” in place of AmazingNewClass when calling class methods:
  AmazingNewClass *instance = [[myClass alloc] init];
} else {
  //The class doesn’t exist
}
```

But it doesn't help anything.  Can someone guide me through what I'd need to do to get my app running on 10.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to weakly link against `AVFoundation.framework`, this allows the link to fail but the process to continue running.

See this Apple [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html).

Comment: Cool, that was simple.  Thanks!